# Eliminar u ocultar headers que revelen información del servidor

Tags: genexus

Hay alguna forma ocultar algunos headers que van en el response de un ws rest?
Probe sobreescribir un header en el HTTPResponse pero en lugar de sobreescribir crear uno nuevo.

[image: Ejemplo de headers devueltos al consumir un ws rest]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Podrías darle una mirada a la siguiente pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without